# Fixing error that occurs when a lot of sprites are colliding

Tags: java, double, game-physics, collision

In the game that I am making I have made it so that the zombies can't go through each other. I did this with this code.

```
for(int i = 0; i < zombies.size(); i++){
                Zombie z = (Zombie) zombies.get(i);
                zombieMovement();
                for(int j = i + 1; j < zombies.size(); j++){
                    Zombie z2 = (Zombie) zombies.get(j);
                    Rectangle r1 = z.getBounds();
                    Rectangle r2 = z2.getBounds();
                    if(r1.intersects(r2)){
                        z.setX(z.getX() - 1);
                        z.setY(z.getY() - 1);
                        z2.setX(z2.getX() + 1);
                        z2.setY(z2.getY() + 1);
                    }
                }
            }
```

the zombieMovement method looks like this.

```
public void zombieMovement(){
        for(int i = 0; i < zombies.size(); i++){ 
            Zombie z = (Zombie) zombies.get(i);
            if(z.getY() > player.getY()){
                z.setY(z.getY() - .01);
            }
            if(z.getY() < player.getY()){
                z.setY(z.getY() + .01);
            }
            if(z.getX() > player.getX()){
                z.setX(z.getX() - .01);
            }
            if(z.getX() < player.getX()){
                z.setX(z.getX() + .01);
            }
            if(z.isAlive()){
                z.move();
            }else{ 
                zombies.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

Because the zombies move 10 times as fast when they are in contact with each other the first couple of zombies move alot faster than the ones that come later because they are in contact with more zombies (I can't set how fast they move when they are in contact with each other to any less because then they will still be able to be inside each other and I don't want the zombies to move any faster than what they are already doing).

Are there any simple ways to fix this error in?

Comment: Your second loop is really strange. Why j=i+1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to fix zombies that overlap you should prevent the problem in the first place in your `zombieMovement()` method. When working out where a zombie moves to you should test to see if its new position (the +/- .01 bit) is already occupied, if so then don't move the zombie to that location.

```
/**
* Returns true if the point x,y is already occupied by a zombie
*/
boolean isOccupied(double x, double y) {
  for (Zombie z : zombies) {
    if (z.getBounds().contains(new Point(x,y))) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

You can then test in your movement method like this;

```
if (z.getY() > player.getY()) {
  double newY = z.getY() - .01;
  if (!isOccupied(z.getX(), newY) {
    z.setY(newY);
  {
}
```

Comment: `for (Zombie z : zombies)` in the `isOccupied` method doesn't work because zombies require `Object` but z is an `Zombie` class and Point require two int's not two doubles

Answer (score 0):

What happens when a zombie is surrounded on all sides and you have to move it?

For a really robust solution, I'd do a simultaneous constraint solver. Essentially, you can think of it like putting a spring in between each colliding zombie and iterating until everyone is no longer intersecting. You'd probably want to put caps on displacement to make sure you don't accidentally have zombies shooting off into space as well.

Unfortunately, this approach requires complicated math. I think Box2d has some slides online explaining the basis of its algorithms. Or you could just use an existing physics engine, like Box2d.